# SharedQueue and SharedQueueExe are logically identical but SharedQueueEx corrupts memory for unknown reasons

Tags: c++, queue, heap-corruption

There are two logically-identical classes: SharedQueue and SharedQueueEx.
Each has a member m_pTail and m_pHead and Recv and Send functions access both in order to access the internal shared queues. In this post, Recv is the one concerned and therefore ignore Send at the moment.

When Recv/Send is entered, m_pTail/m_pHead is always checked for nullity even though once it is initiaized to a non-NULL value it never becomes NULL again during the whole program life cycle.

```
SharedQueue(int nMaxQueueLength = MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH, int nNodeLength = MAX_NODE_LENGTH, unsigned int nDelay = 0)
{
    m_pHead = m_pTail = nullptr;
    ...
}
int Recv(const char* pBuffer, int nLength)
{
    int nRecvLength = 0;
    while (nRecvLength < nLength)
    {
        QNode* pQE = nullptr;
        #pragma region pQE = Enqueue();
        ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
        if (!m_pTail)
            // initialize first node in the list
            pQE = m_pHead = m_pTail = new QNode(0, m_nNodeLength);
        // check if last received node reached its node end
        else if (m_pTail->m_nRecvOffset >= m_nNodeLength)
    ...
}
```

So, I modified SharedQueue a little bit to never check m_pTail's nullity by initializing it in SharedQueue's constructor.  Such modified one is SharedQueueEx.

```
SharedQueueEx(int nMaxQueueLength = MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH, int nNodeLength = MAX_NODE_LENGTH, unsigned int nDelay = 0)
{
    m_pHead = m_pTail = nullptr;
    // pre-allocate the first node in the list
    m_pTail = m_pFirstNode = new QNode(0, m_nNodeLength);
    ...
}
int Recv(const char* pBuffer, int nLength)
{
    int nRecvLength = 0;
    while (nRecvLength < nLength)
    {
        QNode* pQE = nullptr;
        #pragma region pQE = Enqueue();
        ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
        // check if last received node reached its node end
        if (m_pTail->m_nRecvOffset >= m_nNodeLength)
        {
            // check if queue reached its maximum length
            int nNewSequence = m_pTail->m_nSequence + 1;
            if (nNewSequence >= m_nMaxQueueLength)
            {
                if (!m_pHead)
                    m_pHead = m_pFirstNode;
    ...
}
```

Both SharedQueue and SharedQueueExe are logically identical. I can confirm it by creating each instance at the same time and calling Recv with identical input. Within debugger, I checked each and every Recv call from both instances and they work exactly the same.

However, when exiting the test program, its memory somehow gets corrupted by SharedQueueEx.
I spent lots of time to figure it out why, but failed and here I am asking for a help.

For your easy testing, I uploaded the runnable VC2017 solution to OneDrive and the link is shown for downloading:

[SharedQueueTest.zip](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiVorOunaPYdrnsKoFLQTWzQiMUM?e=lm3ZhQ)

In SharedQueueTest.cpp line 16:

```
#define TEST_SQEX
```

First run it by commenting out the above macro to see it is working fine.
Then try again with the macro defined to see the program will crash when exiting and give out:

[image: HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED]

Please check what is wrong with SharedQueueEx and let me know.

Thanks a lot.

[PS] If you want to know how SharedQueue works, please refer to the following CodeProject link:
[How SharedQueue works](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224733/Real-time-Feed-Distribution-using-Circular-Shared?msg=5842227#xx5842227xx)

[PS] The attached project source needs to be modified as follows:

**Source modified (and uploaded to OneDrive)**

```
int CFeedClient::Send(const char* lpcs, int nLength)
{
    UINT r1 = random(0, nLength);
    UINT r2 = random(0, nLength);
    UINT nSent = (r1 > r2) ? (r1 - r2 + 1) : (r1 < r2) ? (r2 - r1 + 1) : 0;
    return nSent;
}

unsigned __stdcall RecvThreadFunc(LPVOID pParam)
{
    int nLength;
    char szbuf[] = "`~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}\\|,./<>?0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    ATLASSERT(strlen(szbuf) == _countof(szbuf) - 1);    // not counting the terminating NULL
    while (bContRecv)
    {
        // Recv feed from some where
        //... // (fill szBuf and nLength), data can be processed or transformed
        // save received feed in the queue
        UINT r1 = random(0, _countof(szbuf) - 2);   // not counting the terminating NULL
        UINT r2 = random(0, _countof(szbuf) - 2);   // not counting the terminating NULL
        if (r1 > r2)
        {
            nLength = r1 - r2 + 1;
            #if defined(TEST_SQEX)
            sqEx.Recv(szbuf + r2, nLength );
            #else // TEST_SQEX
            sq  .Recv(szbuf + r2, nLength );
            #endif // TEST_SQEX
        }
        else if (r1 < r2)
        {
            nLength = r2 - r1 + 1;
            #if defined(TEST_SQEX)
            sqEx.Recv(szbuf + r1, nLength );
            #else // TEST_SQEX
            sq  .Recv(szbuf + r1, nLength );
            #endif // TEST_SQEX
        }
        //else if (r1 == r2)
        //  continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**[PS] The simplest way to reproduce the heap corruption is to replace the main() and ~CSharedQueueEx() as follows (just one-time direct Recv call in the primary thread without creating a separate thread at all):**

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    char szbuf[] = "`~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}\\|,./<>?0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    ATLASSERT(strlen(szbuf) == _countof(szbuf) - 1);    // not counting the terminating NULL
    int nLength = 0;

    // Recv feed from some where
    //... // (fill szBuf and nLength), data can be processed or transformed
    // save received feed in the queue
    UINT r1 = random(0, _countof(szbuf) - 2);   // not counting the terminating NULL
    UINT r2 = random(0, _countof(szbuf) - 2);   // not counting the terminating NULL
    if (r1 > r2)
    {
        nLength = r1 - r2 + 1;
        #if defined(TEST_SQEX)
        sqEx.Recv(szbuf + r2, nLength );
        #else // TEST_SQEX
        sq  .Recv(szbuf + r2, nLength );
        #endif // TEST_SQEX
    }
    else if (r1 < r2)
    {
        nLength = r2 - r1 + 1;
        #if defined(TEST_SQEX)
        sqEx.Recv(szbuf + r1, nLength );
        #else // TEST_SQEX
        sq  .Recv(szbuf + r1, nLength );
        #endif // TEST_SQEX
    }
    return 0;
}
~SharedQueueEx()
{
    ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    // clear all nodes
    try
    {
        #if defined(TEST_SQEX)
        if (!m_pHead)
            m_pHead = m_pFirstNode;
        #endif // TEST_SQEX
        for (QNode* pNext; m_pHead; m_pHead = pNext)
            pNext = m_pHead->m_pNext, delete m_pHead;
        m_pHead = m_pTail = nullptr;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
    ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    ::DeleteCriticalSection(&m_cs);
}
```

You will get "Heap Corruption..." popup when the program exits.
[image: HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED...]

Comment: BTW, did you try using the debugger (which should come with VS)? Maybe apply breakpoints on certain lines and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Then the issue would likely be caused by the “lack of m_pTail check” (or another change), no?

Comment: I think, it's because of `m_pHead` I guess. Head should function as the head of the queue - it should point to the first element right? But in your code, I am not sure if it does that. Also, I don't understand your logic when the node reaches its end.

Comment: @kiner_shah I did try debugging with VS debugger but I couldn't find out what is wrong at all.  That's why I posted here. And m_pHead surely points to the first node.
As I mentioned in the post, it works ok but when the program exits, the heap corruption happens.

Why don't you try to run it yourself to see the issue please?

Comment: @user64740 No, that is not the case at all. m_pTail is always valid during the program run.  When the program exits, the heap corruption happens. Please run it yourself.

Comment: @here The source project was modified a bit and uploaded to OneDrive.  If you download it before, download it once again.  The main crash issue still remains the same, though.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Would you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason. Just a simple bug unnoticed at all.
Initially, the SharedQueueEx's constructor was:

```
SharedQueueEx(int nMaxQueueLength = MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH, int nNodeLength = MAX_NODE_LENGTH, unsigned int nDelay = 0)
{
    m_bRealTime = true;
    m_pHead = m_pTail = nullptr;
    // pre-allocate the first node in the list
    m_pTail = m_pFirstNode = new QNode(0, m_nNodeLength);
    m_nMaxQueueLength = (nMaxQueueLength > MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH ? MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH : nMaxQueueLength);
    m_nNodeLength = (nNodeLength > MAX_NODE_LENGTH ? MAX_NODE_LENGTH : nNodeLength);
    m_nDelay = nDelay;
    ::InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
}
```

m_nNodeLength in 'new QNode(0, m_nNodeLenght)' was not initialized.

**It should be like this:**

```
SharedQueueEx(int nMaxQueueLength = MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH, int nNodeLength = MAX_NODE_LENGTH, unsigned int nDelay = 0)
{
    m_nMaxQueueLength = (nMaxQueueLength > MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH ? MAX_QUEUE_LENGTH : nMaxQueueLength);
    m_nNodeLength = (nNodeLength > MAX_NODE_LENGTH ? MAX_NODE_LENGTH : nNodeLength);
    m_nDelay = nDelay;
    m_bRealTime = true;
    m_pHead = m_pTail = nullptr;
    // pre-allocate the first node in the list
    m_pTail = m_pFirstNode = new QNode(0, m_nNodeLength);
    ::InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
}
```